# Tengo que hacer un método que invierta los valores de una lista enlazada

Tags: c++, lista

Tengo que hacer que los valores de la lista se inviertan utilizando un método y mandando por referencia esta lista y con ayuda de otra lista invertirla, tal como se muestra en el código pero me da un error no entiendo muy bien por que.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

**(Todo esto en C++)**

```
template <class T>
void Inv(T &list){
    Lista <int> *list1 = new Lista <int> ;
    list1=list;
    for (Nodo <T> *val;val!=NULL;val=val->sig){
        T list1->Ins_Ini(val->info); //<---- aqui me da un error "expected initializer before '->' token
        list1->Eli_Fin();
    }
}
```

Comment: claro, pero si se la quito me marca error con tipos de datos me dice que es invalida la conversión de Lista<int> * a 'int'

Comment: Por favor, trata de incluir siempre el error completo (no tu resumen del mensaje). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

```
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ llamada a función
   T list1->Ins_Ini(val->info);
// ^ tipo
```

Te sobra el `T`.

La línea podrías dejarla como

```
T list1;
```

en cuyo caso estarías declarando una nueva variable de tipo `T`, o así:

```
list1->Ins_Ini(val->info);
```

En cuyo caso se invocaría una llamada a la función `Ins_Ini`... entiendo que este sería el comportamiento esperado